# How do I update all the Unicorn instances?

Tags: ruby, unicorn

In deploying via Nginx/Unicorn, an issue for me is how to get in touch with running instances. I need this to update the in-memory cache of the app.

With Nginx/Thin, I run multiple instances on various ports and calling app instance by port, like:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl :2000/update_cache/page_id
curl :2001/update_cache/page_id
etc.
```

Ugly approach but it works, cause i can update the cache of a single page(from many thousands) on all running app instances.

I wonder how I can do the same with Unicorn, but not by port. Does Unicorn provide a list of running instances or somewhat a way to interact with them?

The issue with in-memory cache is that when updating it on some instance, it is normally not updated on other ones, so I get content discrepancy because some users see updated content and others yet stays with old content.

How do I update the cache for all Unicorn instances?

Comment: You should just not be using an in-memory cache when running multiple workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, can you get the list of workers PIDs?

If so, you can manage them by sending signals.

Ruby plays well with Unix signals, you just need to catch them and perform needed internal operations.

A simple proof of concept:

```
Signal.trap 'INFO' do
    puts "Updating %s" % Process.pid
    # clear cache ...
end
```

Now if you have the workers PIDs, you simply do:

```
#!/bin/bash
for pid in $pids; do
    kill -s INFO $pid
done
```

You can use any signal instead of INFO.

For list of signals see the Ruby `Signal.list`

To get the list of workers PIDs, see Unicorn's `after_fork` config.

Comment: that's it! stay back! i have now a fully controlled Unicorn App! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The unicorn master process opens the listening port, and the workers are constantly competing to accept requests on that port. There's no way to select individual workers, other than [sending them Unix signals](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html).

This is one of many reasons why caching shouldn't be done like this :)

Comment: disapointed :( will have to use Unicorn only on projects without internal cache

Comment: Or incorporate an application version number or other arbitrarily mutable token in your cache keys, so that you can increment it at will, effectively invalidating previous cache.